# JSP - MySQL - Automatic addition of \r\n with the where clause attribute

Tags: mysql, jsp, select, where-clause

I am working on a jsp project and querying the data from MYSql database. I am facing the following problem:
When the following query executes, it sometimes integrates \r\n with the text (some times between and sometime at the end of the text)  in the value of the description attribute entered in the desc variable. And i do not get the name, while it is there. 'description' in the xyz_table is VARCHAR(500).

```
String retrieveName= "Select name from xyz_table WHERE description = ?";
String desc = "a long text - less than 500 characters - has the description of the name attribute values.";
pst =currentConection.prepareStatement(retrieveName);
pst.setString(1, desc);
resultSet = pst.executeQuery();

if (resultSet.next()){
       String name = resultSet.getString("name");                
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the value of the `desc` variable from? Is it from some HTML form (e.g. via `request.getParameter(...)`)?

Comment: Yes it is from a form. I have debugged the code. All remains fine. desc gets the correct value. but when the prepared statement executes, it appends \r\n. Also it does not happen with all values.

Comment: Problem solved. desc gets value from form, but form is placing those values from xyz_table table. In description column, some values had \r\n embedded in them, which was not visible when I tried to view in MySQL workbench. I updated all of them, and the problem resolved.